# Spring BeanUtils couldn't instantiate generic class

Tags: java, spring, generics

I am trying to implement something for converting between my Entities and DTO.

I have base class for my DTOs (called Models):

```
public class BaseModel<Entity> implements Model<Entity> {

    @Override
    public Entity toEntity(Class<Entity> entityClass) {
        Entity entityInstance = BeanUtils.instantiate(entityClass);
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(this, entityInstance);
        return entityInstance;
    }
}
```

But following test doesn't passes:

```
public class BaseModelTest {

    @Entity
    public class SomeEntity {
        @Id
        private Long id;
        private String name;

        public SomeEntity() {
        }

        public SomeEntity(Long id, String name) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
        }

        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void toEntity_givenEntityClass_shouldCreateNewInstance() throws Exception {
        //given
        BaseModel<SomeEntity> model = new BaseModel();

        //when
        SomeEntity entity = model.toEntity(SomeEntity.class);

        //then
        assertNotNull(entity);
    }
}
```

I got exception: (despite the fact, under debugger I see all ctors):

```
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [package.BaseModelTest$SomeEntity]: Is it an abstract class?; nested exception is java.lang.InstantiationException: package.BaseModelTest$SomeEntity

Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: package.BaseModelTest$SomeEntity
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: package.BaseModelTest$SomeEntity.<init>()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently to create a new `SomeEntity` instance you need an instance of the enclosing `BaseModelTest` class. `SomeEntity` should be an inner static class. Replace:

```
public class SomeEntity {
```

with

```
public static class SomeEntity {
```

BTW. There is no point in having a DTO class if it maps 1-1 to a model class, it does not add any value, it is only boilerplate code.

Comment: Thanks you so much! It's an inner class issue. Also it works if inner Model class is replaced by "normal" class

Comment: Yes, putting `SomeEntity` in `SomeEntity.java` also fixes the issue.

Comment: @BTW I don't want to mix JPA with JSR-303 or Jackson annotations.

Comment: Ok, I guess you might ask a separate question whether DTOs should be used in your case. My recommendation is, try to avoid using DTOs for as long as possible. Unfortunately I have to admit there are situations when they are inevitable.